# Numpy Version error when installing mljar-supervised

Tags: python, numpy, numba, mljar

I am working on a new conda environment with python 3.9. When I try to install mljar-supervised everything works as it should and it gives no errors. However when I try to import the package I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 0x10 but this version of numpy is 0xe
```

The installation installs in my case numpy 1.22.4. I tried upgrading it to 1.23.0 but then it still doesn't work, since 1.23.0 is not supported by the latest version of numba and I get a different error. My numba version is 0.56.0.